# MySQL self join запрос

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблица с полями `(itsDate, itsName, itsPlace, itsQuant)`

и в ней значения

```
("2018-05-31","киви","город 2","12")
("2018-05-31","яблоко","город 1","10")
("2018-05-31","груша","город 1","5")
("2018-05-31","груша","город 2","11")
("2018-04-30","яблоко","город 2","4")
("2018-04-30","яблоко","город 1","5")
("2018-04-30","груша","город 1","6")
("2018-04-30","банан","город 1","7")
```

Нужно получить такую выборку

```
яблоко, город 1, +5
яблоко, город 2, -4
груша,  город 1, -1
груша,  город 2, +11
банан,  город 1, -7
банан,  город 2,  0  -- ммм или даже не надо эту строчку - разницы нет
киви,   город 1,  0  --тоже разницы нет выводить или нет
киви,   город 2, +12
```

двигаюсь в данном направлении

```
select
  sum(t2.itsQuant - t1.itsQuant) 
from
  (select * from table where itsDate = '2018-04-30') as t1
  join (select * from table where itsDate = '2018-05-31') as t2 on
    t1.itsName = t2.itsName and t1.itsPlace = t2.itsPlace
group by
  t2.itsName, t2.itsPlace
```

НО join только выбирает те элементы которые есть в обоих городах на обе даты
`full outer join` - выдает ошибку - читай документацию

но даже если с этим разберусь то как я понял для тех позиции которых нет в одном из городов или на одну из дат будут выдаваться NULL и счет вероятно не произойдет

думал про self join - как то совсем не получается

Comment: Ни хрена не понял, но... *даже если с этим разберусь то как я понял для тех позиции которых нет в одном из городов или на одну из дат будут выдаваться NULL* Сначала надо в подзапросе получить все имеющиеся пары (itsName, itsPlace), и к нему LEFT JOIN двух копий таблицы. Ну а Null легко заменяется на ноль функцией COALESCE(). **PS.** Вы бы лучше объяснили, какая логика позволяет из "в ней значения" состряпать "такую выборку"...

Comment: Да я действительно. задал вопрос без вопроса. Цель все таки не получить такую выборку а вытащить изменения по всем продуктам в разрезе города с даты1 на дату 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select itsName, itsPlace, sum(if(itsDate='2018-05-31',itsQuant,-itsQuant)) 
  from tab
 group by itsName, itsPlace
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e8b1/1)

Если используется СУБД не поддерживающая `if`, заменить его на `case`

Comment: Решение красивое, при условии, что в БД лежат данные только за два дня

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Если не за два, то добавить where на эти 2 дня или изменить условие в sum

Comment: Решение офигенное. Огромное спасибо. да в базе естесно много дат.  добавление where все решается. еще раз премного благодарен

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  t1.itsName,
  t1.itsPlace,
  t1.itsQuant - coalesce(t2.itsQuant, 0)
from
  mytable t1
  left join mytable t2 on (
    t1.itsName = t2.itsName and 
    t1.itsPlace = t2.itsPlace and
    t2.itsDate = '2018-04-30'
  )
where
  t1.itsDate = '2018-05-31'
union
select
  t2.itsName,
  t2.itsPlace,
  coalesce(t1.itsQuant, 0) - t2.itsQuant
from
  mytable t2
  left join mytable t1 on (
    t1.itsName = t2.itsName and 
    t1.itsPlace = t2.itsPlace and
    t1.itsDate = '2018-05-31'
  )
where
  t2.itsDate = '2018-04-30'
```